# Arcanist automatically populate reviewers line based on arc cover

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

If you run `arc cover` it will show you who last edited the lines you have changed, which is good for deciding who should be reviewers.

Is there a way to have Arcanist automatically do this and then pre-populate the `Reviewers:` line in the commit message with those people?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a delimited list of reviewers with this one liner:

`arc cover | grep '^[^ ]' | paste -s -d, -`

And you can specify reviewers when creating a diff, using the `--reviewers` option.

Therefore you should be able to do something like this:

`arc diff --reviewers "$(arc cover | grep '^[^ ]' | paste -s -d, -)"`

But this only works if you use Phabricator usernames as git author names.